# Loop for UIViewSubClass on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiview

In my app i have custom view subclass of UIView, let's say i wanna remove all my UIView from my main view i will use :

```
for (UIView *aView in self.view.subviews)
{
    [aView removeFromSuperView];
}

for (ViewAlertiPad *anAler in self.view.subviews)
{
    [anAler.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [anAler removeFromSuperview];
}

for (CALayer* layer in [self.view.layer sublayers])
{
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

But how can i loop from all subclass of UIView in my main view ?

Comment: Can you explain it more? I can't get you. Every visible thing( UIButton, UILabel, UIImageView) is a subclass of UIView, and if you loop in [self.view subviews] and remove all subviews, it will remove everything from your main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
for (UIView *aView in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]]) {
        [aView removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  In your post you said that `CustomView` was a subclass of `UIView`.  Your `CustomView`s are in your view's `subviews` along with all the other types of `UIView`s, right?